# Is Eta interoprable with Java and/or Kotlin yet?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, jvm, eta

I've been learning Haskell, but during my day job I am writing Kotlin/Java.

I've come across Eta (https://eta-lang.org/), a Haskell dialect that compiles to Java byte code and runs on the JVM. On the website it states that it has:

```
Robust Interoperability

Eta has a strongly-typed Foreign Function Interface (FFI) that allows you to safely interoperate with Java.
```

But further down the page there is a "Coming Soon" section, where the interop is listed. So my question, before I go to the hassle of setting up an environment to dev in:

Is this officially supported yet?

Comment: This (https://eta-lang.org/docs/user-guides/eta-user-guide/java-interop/java-interop-basics) suggests there is Eta supports Java-interop.

Comment: Why you're learning Haskell?0

Comment: Because I think it has a lot of concepts that, once learned, can be applied in more mainstream languages that allow for FP. And, because learning a purely functional lazy language is an interesting challenge in and of itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing that's "Coming soon" is the "bindings generator". [Eta has implemented syntax](https://eta-lang.org/docs/user-guides/eta-user-guide/java-interop/java-interop-basics) for Java interop, but you need to explicitly write foreign declarations for each Java entity you want to call. E.g. as in the linked example, a class like

```java
public class Counter {
    private int counter = 0;
    private final int max;
    public Counter(int max) { this.max = max; }
    public int postIncrement() { return max == counter ? counter : counter++; }
}
```

necessitates a block of foreign imports

```hs
data Counter = Counter @example.Counter deriving Class
foreign import java unsafe "@new" newCounter :: Int -> Java a Counter
foreign import java unsafe "postIncrement" postIncrement :: Java Counter Int
```

As you might guess, it would be preferable for this to be auto-generated. The program to do that generation is what's WIP, not the FFI itself.

Comment: Any ETA for that? :P

Comment: @ThomasCook: Sadly, Eta is abandonware since around 2019. I can't find that page anymore, but the Eta lead developer announced somewhere that he got hired (i.e. "got a real job") and was thus left with very little free time to dedicate to his side projects.